# Emberjs ,i dont know where take mistake

Tags: ember.js

first,i can watch the data in blogs template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="blogs">
<div>  
<div>
 {{#linkTo 'blogs' }}bogsCategory{{/linkTo}}
</div>
<ul>
    {{#each controller}}
       <li>{{title}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>  
  </script>
```

then , build a new template "blogs/index" , to render into the blogs, but now, there nothing on my page.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="blogs/index">
  <ul>
    {{#each controller}}
       <li>{{title}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>  
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="blogs">
    <div>  
    <div>
     {{#linkTo 'blogs' }}bogsCategory{{/linkTo}}
    </div>
    {{ outlet }}
    </div>  
      </script>
```

i don't know where take mistake and how to do

Route:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('blogs', { path: '/'});
});


App.BlogsIndexRoute=Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return App.Blog.find();
  }
});
```

[enter link description here](http://jsbin.com/ikituj/12/edit)

<----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

i want build a blog pag,  the left is blogscategory, right is blog list, when i first into page,  use 'blogs/index' to Initialization 'blogs', when click the blogscategory the blogs content will change by the category.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here at your working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ikituj/23/edit).

Basically I've changed `BlogsIndexRoute` to `BlogsRoute` and renamed the `blogs` template to `application`. Now it correctly renders the `blogs/index` template into the `application` template. I hope this is what you where trying to achieve.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i use 'blogs/index' to Initialization 'blogs',the 'blogs' content can change when i click <a> .

look here http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Comment: @fung, I didn't see any `<a>` in your code, but it would still work if there where to change the content of the `outlet` beeing in the `application` template or not.

Comment: @fung, where is the <a> ?

Comment: i want build a blog pag, the left is blogscategory, right is blog list, when i first into page, use 'blogs/index' to Initialization 'blogs', when click the blogscategory the blogs content will change by the category.